# Tycho build fails with with java 6

Tags: maven, tycho

I need to compile a an eclipse RCP using maven+tycho, at the moment everything is working fine, as I configured this on my local PC.

When switching to production-building configuration, it fails, the only difference being java version used.

- Works with: Java jdk1.8.0_25
- Fails with: Java jdk1.6.0_45

Error message:

> ATTENTION: Error injecting: org.eclipse.tycho.core.p2.P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout
>
> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.p2.P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout not present
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/tycho/core/p2/P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I can provide the full error stack if needed, but the error message seems pretty explicit already. Still, didn't find anything about it on the web, because it feels strange that this can't be done using java 1.6.

When using java jdk 8, I don't have any errors and the build is working fine till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Tycho require Java 8 (`.class` file version 52.0 means Java 8). You can, however, still **build** against an older Java (and run tests with an older Java) using a feature called [toolchains](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Execution_Environments#Toolchains). That way, `mvn` runs on Java 8, while your code is compiled against Java 6.

Comment: Fixed the issue but now I get an error saying that "String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" when I'm using the jdk6 I provided using toolchain.

Comment: The tycho version 0.24 works with JDK 7...the next version 0.25 requires JDK 8 as far as I know...